# PDF/CHM library manager software

Tags: pdf, file-management, chm, organizer-software

I'm looking for software to help me organize/manage my collection of technical .pdfs (and older .chm) files. If it can handle other formats thats fine, though at bare minimum it should handle pdfs.

The software should work on Windows XP or higher. Commercial, freeware, or open source is fine.

I'm looking for software like [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) (which appears to be pretty good)

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at [Koobits](http://www.koobits.com/)? It does not do chm format, but you could use a chm-to-pdf converter. There are many of these converters available online or as a download.

Comment: That looks good...are there any others? I remember when I looked back in '01 for some organizers, I found a lot, but I didn't have enough books to really warrant one. Today, I can hardly find any.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly intended for this purpose, but if Calibre is the sort of thing you're looking at, I would look at [ComicRack](http://comicrack.cyolito.com/).  It has full PDF support (I think pretty much anything will require you to convert those CHMs to PDF), full metadata capabilities, scripting functionality, remote sharing functionality, tons of visual options, completely customizable hotkeys, and is actively developed by a very astute and responsive developer.  (Disclaimer: I am fairly active on those forums with said developer so I might be a bit biased, but simple feature requests are usually added in short order.)

Honestly, though, Calibre itself may be best for you.